# Spring boot 1.4.1 Maven Eclipse Error 88252

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, spring-boot, eclipse-neon

I use Eclipse Neon, configured with embedded maven 3.3.9

When I add to my pom.xml

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
```

and I try to run Maven Update I get the error:

> An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project".
>       88252

And the dependency jars are not added to Maven Dependencies tree.

If I run `mvn clean package -U` it builds correctly, both from command line and Eclipse (Run As Maven..)

If I change back to `1.4.0.RELEASE` everything works fine! 
Any Idea?

Comment: What happens when you try to do a 'mvn clean package -U' from command line?

Comment: If I run mvn clean package -U it build corretcly, both from command line and from eclipse (Run As Maven..) , I Edit the question

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to some broken package in my local maven repository.

I delete the entire `<home_dir>/.m2/repository/org/springframework/` directory, I ran `Maven Update` again and everything turned normal!